# How to display data in a table horizontally?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to display these data horizontally, the problem is it overlaps the headers and it only creates duplicate entry on 1st and 2nd rows of the table.

Here is an example of the problem:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | No Column | No Column | No Column | No Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 30 | 25 | 15 | 10 |
| #2 | 20 | 30 | 40 | . 50. | 30 | 25 | 15 | 10 |

What the correct should be is:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
| #2 | 30 | 25 | 15 | . 10 |

I've already construct the table like this:

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        <tbody class="text-center">
                        <?php foreach($candidatesf as $candidate): ?>
                            
                            <tr> <td><?php echo $candidate['fullname'] ?></td>
                            <?php foreach($candscores as $candscore): ?>
                                <?php  echo "\t<td>"; ?><?php echo $candscore['score']; ?></td>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <tr></tr>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the table row 
Then you add some td elements.
At the end, you open another  and close that one.

You have a syntax error here:

```
<tr></tr>
```

You should only close it like this:

```
</tr>
```

Comment: Still having the same result, sir.

Comment: Then you have 9 columns in your input data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <tbody class="text-center">
    <?php foreach($candidatesf as $candidate): ?>       
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $candidate['fullname'] ?></td>
            <?php foreach($candscores as $candscore): ?>
                <td><?php echo $candscore['score']; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: it gives the same result, sir.

Comment: @AnonSyn can you share the array?